# How to use IPN/PDT to display receipt and digital and/or downloadable products after purchase and redirection with PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, eclipse-pdt

I have a webshop: energyshop.se which I have successfully managed to setup a Sandbox account at PayPal and to create a Buyer and a Seller account, created a button which I implemented to my site (from the Seller account) and I manage to make a payment through my Buyer account and got redirection to work too, to energyshop.se/tack.

So far so good, now I wonder how do I reach the "product ID" that IPN/PDT sends when the user is redirected? How do I use that holder to display files for download or just for play/listening? And what are the holders/variable that holds the receipt information? I would like to say for example when returned to /tack to display the receipt and then the downloadable item.

Any help is very welcome I have worked n this site for ages now and just want it done, it is for a customer too.

I tried to do something like this (i use wordpress at my thankyoupage):

```
<div id="receiptform">
<form method=post action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_notify-synch"> 
<input type="hidden" name="tx" value="TransactionID"> 
<input type="hidden" name="at" value="P0d7_HmQSAuXh9r-7hG1Rzf_npI2LaFgYHQJyWUsjQHg7WhZARqs3sq6IW4"> 
<input type="submit" value="PDT"> 
</form>
</div>
```

But that just displays a button PDT that when clicked displyas FAIL ERROR: 4002 
How do I edit this to just display the content nicely in tx?

Also, I can tell that "its" working because in the address field, when redirected to thank-you-page this reads: http://energyshop.se/tack/?tx=9LJ24270G46097059&st=Completed&amt=10.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=1 which leads me to think its A) completed and B) got the info I need. Now is the question how i present this data? What am I supposed to do? A php-script that I...? I cant seem to find any examples on it, just the defnition of the variables for IPN/PDT but that doesnt help me if I dont know where to put or do with it...

Comment: I cant seem to get this: now i tried to use PayPals own code at https://paypaltech.com/SG2/PHPfunctionalityparse.php which "This script writes all posted IPN variables and values to an HTML page." and pointed to that php's url to the redirection url after purchase, as i did earlier with my /thankyou. Only nothing is displayed, just a blank page, but with the same address in it, meaning it "works": http://energyshop.se/wp-content/themes/blank/thanks.php?tx=40R75438H13401724&st=Completed&amt=10.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use PDT as you are.  When you receive the tx variable and etc back, you have to do a post back to PayPal to verify all of the inforamtion.  Then once you have varified the post, PayPal will then send all of the variables back to your script.  You can find a bit more on how PDT works at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNPDTAnAlternativetoIPN.  There are also some sample scripts on that site as well at https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216627 and https://paypaltech.com/PDTGen/

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it setup correct... I get the data sent to me which I can manipulate and emal is sent to customer. I hope its secure enough!